# Sorting multiple columns from a CSV file in Python

Tags: sorting, csv, python-3.x

I am a secondary school teacher attempting to find an appropriate way to teach KS4 pupils techniques that will allow them to write data to a CSV file and then read that same data from a file and display it back in Python in an organised structure.
Pupils and I have a clear understanding of how to write the data to the file however in terms of getting the data from the file into Python and then sorting it is becoming rather tricky and complex to explain.

I've created a program that allows the user to input their name followed by 3 separate numbers all of which get written to the CSV file in the format shown below...

```
James , 3 , 7 , 4
David , 5 , 5 , 9
Steven , 8 , 3 , 9
```

These results are saved in a file "7G1.csv"

So far I have a functioning program that sorts alphabetically, highest to lowest and by average highest to lowest. I have been able to establish through research and piecing together techniques from numerous sources the following program but can anybody suggest an easier more efficient approach that could be understood by 16 year olds.

```
import csv

G1 = open('7G1.csv')
csv_G1 = csv.reader(G1)
list7G1 = []
for column in csv_G1:
    column[1] = int(column[1])
    column[2] = int(column[2])
    column[3] = int(column[3]) 
    minimum = min(column[1:4])
    column.append(minimum)
    maximum = max(column[1:4])
    column.append(maximum)
    average = round(sum(column[1:4])/3)
    column.append(average)
    list7G1.append(column[0:7])

group_menu = 0
while group_menu != 4:
    group_menu = int(input("Which group / class do you want to look at?\n1.7G1?\n2.7G2?\n3.7G3?\n4.Quit? "))                     
    if group_menu == 1:
        print ("You have chosen to focus on group 7G1.")
        menu = int(input("\nDo you want to...\n1.Sort Alphabetically?\n2.Sort Highest to Lowest?\n3.Sort Average Highest to Lowest?\n4.Exit Group? "))
        while menu != 4:
            if menu == 1:
                print("You have chosen to Sort Alphabetically...")
                namesList = [[x[0], x[5]] for x in list7G1]
                print("\nSorted Alphabetically with Highest Scores \n")
                for names in sorted(namesList):
                    print (names)
            elif menu == 2:
                print("You have chosen to Sort Highest to Lowest...")
                highestScore = [[x[5], x[0]] for x in list7G1]
                print("\nScores Highest to Lowest \n")
                for hightolow in sorted(highestScore, reverse = True):
                    print (hightolow)
            elif menu == 3:
                print("You have chosen to Sort Average Highest to Lowest")
                averageScore = [[x[6], x[0]] for x in list7G1]
                print("\nAverage Scores \n")
                for average in sorted(averageScore, reverse = True):
                    print(average)
            elif menu == 4:
                print("You have chosen to exit this group")
            else:
                print("This is not a valid option")
            menu = int(input("\nDo you want to...\n1.Sort Alphabetically?\n2.Sort Highest to Lowest?\n3.Sort Average Highest to Lowest?\n4.Exit Group? "))
```

Any suggestions on how to simplify this program would be hugely appreciated.